# How to finish drywall where it meets shiplap ceiling?

Tags: drywall, ceiling

Obviously, I cannot tape and mud the seam. Is the solution as simple as only mudding over the drywall screws once the sheetrock is in place? Is a J-bead necessary or would it improve this situation? Moulding is not an option.[image]

Comment: I would do a [tear-away L-bead](https://www.trim-tex.com/products/tear-away-l-bead).  Why isn't trim an option?

Comment: Ideal way if you don't want any trim would be to install the ceiling after finishing the wall.

Comment: I don't quite understand how a tear-away L-bead helps in this situation. I would still have to mud along the top seam of the drywall, and then I would have a bead running across the top of the shiplap. Moulding is not an option because there is no moulding along any of the shiplap. All walls join the shiplap with drywall edges.

Comment: One consideration is the flatness of the shiplap installation. In the picture the drywall straight edge butts nicely to the shiplap. There may be other places, especially along the length of a ceiling, where things won't look so neat.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the solution as simple as only mudding over the drywall screws once the sheetrock is in place?

Yes, assuming you're okay with how the result looks.

Normally, drywall has a dip so that mudding is easier so if that doesn't bother you then you can follow your plan.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Molding is always an option - sometimes it just takes more work.

Yeah, that would look fine. The drywall is typically a bit thinner at the edges, to make room for the tape, but nobody will even notice that unless the light is just right *and* they're looking right at it.

People very rarely look at ceilings, unless they're lying in bed. Save your energy for the walls.